# How to add new menu to Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I need to add a new menu in Visual Studio 2015.

I have been able to add new menus to the tools, or the project, as the context menu of the code, but I failed to find the pair of values ​​guid and parentid to be included in my file `.vcst` for a new entry in the IDE at same level of Tools, File etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **Menu** element with **<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS" />**.

Comment: In VS 2019, everything goes under the Extensions menu, even if you specify a specific menu such as IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS.  Can you please comment on it if you have the time? Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu Yes it is, unfortunately. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/435711/get-rid-of-new-extensions-menu.html